# How to call the eval method of a Java class from Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

If a certain Java class has a method called "eval", how can I call it from Clojure?

Doing the following seems to call the eval method from the clojure.core instead of TestObject's eval:

```
(defn test[x] 
  (let [obj (new TestObject)] 
    (. obj eval x)))
```

Comment: That does not seem to be true - what makes you think that?

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn test[x] 
  (let [obj (new TestObject)] 
    (.eval obj x)))
```

**Edit.** However it's very strange. The Dot special form `.` expects a symbol as second parameter and the name of this symbol is interpreted as a name of class method/field. So `eval` can't be evaluated to `eval` function in your case.

Comment: @EmreColak Does it eliminate the problem?